# Use of parametrized stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, user-defined-functions, prepared-statement

I am trying to invoke the stored procedure in my C# application but it is not really invoking I tried so much tried call it `ExecuteReader`, `NonReader`, `Scalar` etc. but still it not getting executed I am displaying my whole code below including sql commands which ever I used

Please check out that what really is the problem in my code

Thanks in Advance

`Stock` table

```
Create Table Stock
(
--S_ID int Primary Key identity (1,1),
Date_of_Added Datetime Default (getdate()),
EnvType nvarchar(10),
TypeSize nvarchar(10),
Size nvarchar(10),
[Description] sql_variant,
Qty int,
Quality int,
)
```

`NewProduct` table

```
Create Table NewProduct
(

MS nvarchar(30),
Date_of_Added Datetime Default (getdate()),
Invoice_No nvarchar(20),
Challan_No nvarchar(20),
EnvType nvarchar(10),
TypeSize nvarchar(10),
Size nvarchar(10),
Description sql_variant,
Qty int,
Quality int,
PayState nvarchar(10),
Balanace_Amount money,
PaymentMode nvarchar(6),
Cheque_No int,
BankDetails nvarchar(30),
P_UnitPrice money,
P_Price money
)

-- Creating trigger of above stored procedure to update or insert the stock as needed
Create Procedure StockProc
(@EnvType nvarchar(50),@TypeSize nvarchar(50),@Size nvarchar(50),@Desc Sql_variant,@Qty    int,@Quality int)
As Begin

if exists (select S.EnvType, S.TypeSize, S.Size, S.[Description], S.Qty, S.Quality
from NewProduct NP Full Join Stock S
on(NP.Size=NP.Size)
where NP.Size=@Size and NP.TypeSize=@TypeSize and NP.EnvType=@EnvType and  NP.Quality=@Quality)
    --Print 'Record Found';
--If Record will found then ut will update the quantity
Begin
    update Stock
    set Qty=NP.Qty+S.Qty
    from NewProduct NP, Stock S
    --have not used IN Operator here as IN works as OR Clause
    where S.EnvType=NP.EnvType and S.TypeSize=NP.TypeSize and S.Size=NP.Size
End
Else
--If no record will match with the enterd data, New Record will be added on Stock Table
Begin
    --Print 'No Record Found'
    insert into Stock (EnvType, TypeSize, Size, [Description], Qty, Quality)
                 values(@EnvType,@TypeSize,@Size,@Desc,@Qty,@Quality)
    --Below Lines will slow down the performance so we are using the above  query
    --Truncate Table Stock
    --insert into Stock (Date_of_Added, EnvType, TypeSize, Size, [Description], Qty, Quality)
    --select Date_of_Added, EnvType, TypeSize, Size, [Description], Qty, Quality from NewProduct
End
End
```

--while testing in sql it works fine you can test it by below exec code

```
exec StockProc 'fdfdf','sdf','dsfs','sdf',4,5
```

C# code:

```
private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            //Will check the connection state if got open then will close the connection
            if (ObjCon.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                ObjCon.con.Close();
            ObjCon.con.Open();

            string Query = "INSERT INTO NewProduct ([MS], [Date_of_Added], [Invoice_No], [Challan_No], [EnvType], [TypeSize], [Size],[Description], [Qty], [Quality], [PayState], [Balanace_Amount], [PaymentMode], [Cheque_No], [BankDetails], [P_UnitPrice], [P_Price])  VALUES ('" + txtMs.Text + "','" + dtpNewProduct.Value + "','" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "','" + txtChallanNo.Text + "','" + cboType.Text + "','" + txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text + "','" + txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text + "','" + txtDesc.Text + "','" + nudQty.Value + "','" + nudQuality.Value + "','" + cboPayState.Text + "','" + txtBalAmt.Text + "','" + cboPayMode.Text + "','" + txtChequeNo.Text + "','" + txtBankNameBranch.Text + "','" + txtPUPrice.Text + "','" + txtPPrice.Text + "')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, ObjCon.con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("StockProc", ObjCon.con);
            //SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("exec StockProc '" + cboType.Text + "','" + txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text + "','" + txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text + "','" + txtDesc.Text + "','" + nudQty.Value + "','" + nudQuality.Value + "'", ObjCon.con);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date_of_Added", dtpNewProduct.Value));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnvType", cboType.Text));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TypeSize", txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Size", txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Desc", txtDesc.Text));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", nudQty.Value));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quality", nudQuality.Value));

            //http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Callstoredprocedureandpassintheparameter.htm
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnvType", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = cboType.Text;
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TypeSize", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text;
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Size", SqlDbType.NVarChar )).Value=txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text;
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Desc", SqlDbType.Variant)).Value=txtDesc.Text;
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty",SqlDbType.Int)).Value= nudQty.Value;
            //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quality", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = nudQuality.Value;

            //SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            //if (dr.HasRows)
            //    MessageBox.Show("FOUND")
            //if (dr.IsClosed == false)
            //{
            //    dr.Close();
            //}
            //dr.Read();
            //cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
            //cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //set Asynchronous Processing=true in conneciton String in order to use BeginExecureNonQuery Method
            //cmd2.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
            //if (cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
               // MessageBox.Show("FOUND");
            //dr.Close();
            ObjCon.con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Your Details has been Saved\rThank You", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Following Error Occur" + ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Please Help......

or Do you think that I should use UDF instead of Stored Procedure

Comment: "it is not really invoking" isn't a good description of what's happening. Are you getting an exception? If so, what?

Comment: At the moment, the code you've presented doesn't *try* to invoke it. You add a bunch of parameters, and that's all. You've commented out the `ExecuteNonQuery` etc calls. What happens if you use `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: nothing, just first query gets executed and no response from the Stored Procedure but if I remove any of the Parameter I directly get the Exception that the "Specified name of the parameter" is missing...

Comment: Firstly, nobody calls Jon Skeet "dude".  Secondly, why not edit the code sample you've provided to reflect what you've actually tried instead of providing commented out code and then struggling to convey what you actually tried?

Comment: I'm also a little concerned about `ObjCon.con` - it looks like a connection object whose lifetime is unknown and its status is not assumed at any given time. Best practice is to create a connection object when you need it (e.g. just before command object creation and invocation) and dispose of it as soon as it's done. If the connection string doesn't change (unlikely!) the connection itself will be pooled by the runtime and not incur any penalty.

Comment: @Poldie Sorry for that, and I have provided that Code with comments so that the people can understand that I had already tried that things....

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer that ObjCon is just and Object of SqlConnection Class which I have specified in another file and had used it by creating it's object and nothing....                                                      public SqlConnection con=null;
        public Connection()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Inventory;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        }

Comment: @MohammedAnsari I stick by what I said in my comment. You're not following best practice by creating a long-lived `SqlConnection`. If you absolutely must do this, then your object needs to implement `IDisposable` and the `Disposable` pattern to take care of managing resources. I'll post an answer which sorta gets to best practice.

Answer (score 0):

In c# Code, check "String query", it is wrongly written after values.

e.g. use @ms instead of control name when using cmd parameters .

Comment: that's perfectly alright, and even hat query works fine I am getting an error in the stored procedure

Comment: you forgot to execute on server 
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You can see that cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); is also commented I mean to say that I had tried that Also....

Comment: try this approach(Without '@'):
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EnvType", cboType.Text));

Comment: You can see the confusion caused by commenting out vital code, I take it?  Or perhaps not, seeing as its been pointed out and you've not corrected it.  Why don't you stop that now, and show exactly what is failing to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe the bug is in your stored procedure, `StockProc`. Use this change (I'm divining intent here, so you may need to tweak it):

```
create Procedure StockProc
(@EnvType nvarchar(50),@TypeSize nvarchar(50),@Size nvarchar(50),@Desc Sql_variant,@Qty    int,@Quality int)
As Begin

if exists (select S.EnvType, S.TypeSize, S.Size, S.[Description], S.Qty, S.Quality
from NewProduct NP inner Join Stock S
on(NP.Size=S.Size)
where NP.Size=@Size and NP.TypeSize=@TypeSize and NP.EnvType=@EnvType and  NP.Quality=@Quality)
--If Record will found then ut will update the quantity
Begin
    Print 'Record Found';
    update Stock
    set Qty=NP.Qty+S.Qty
    from NewProduct NP, Stock S
    --have not used IN Operator here as IN works as OR Clause
    where S.EnvType=NP.EnvType and S.TypeSize=NP.TypeSize and S.Size=NP.Size
End
Else
--If no record will match with the enterd data, New Record will be added on Stock Table
Begin
    Print 'No Record Found'
    insert into Stock (EnvType, TypeSize, Size, [Description], Qty, Quality)
                 values(@EnvType,@TypeSize,@Size,@Desc,@Qty,@Quality)
    --Below Lines will slow down the performance so we are using the above  query
    --Truncate Table Stock
    --insert into Stock (Date_of_Added, EnvType, TypeSize, Size, [Description], Qty, Quality)
    --select Date_of_Added, EnvType, TypeSize, Size, [Description], Qty, Quality from NewProduct
End
End
GO
```

Now, for your C# code. As per my comments, follow the best practices of disposing of connections a.s.a.p.:

```
    private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ObjCon.con.ConnectionString))
            {
                // I assume this was just for testing to show a direct INSERT works when the sproc didn't.
                // Otherwise, I'd be using replaceable parameters rather than straight text values as that
                // makes it quite vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Better yet, make this a sproc as well
                // and use it rather than client-side SQL.
                var query =
                    "INSERT INTO NewProduct ([MS], [Date_of_Added], [Invoice_No], [Challan_No], [EnvType], [TypeSize], [Size],[Description], [Qty], [Quality], [PayState], [Balanace_Amount], [PaymentMode], [Cheque_No], [BankDetails], [P_UnitPrice], [P_Price])  VALUES ('"
                    + txtMs.Text + "','" + dtpNewProduct.Value + "','" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "','"
                    + txtChallanNo.Text + "','" + cboType.Text + "','" + txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text
                    + "','" + txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text + "','" + txtDesc.Text + "','" + nudQty.Value
                    + "','" + nudQuality.Value + "','" + cboPayState.Text + "','" + txtBalAmt.Text + "','"
                    + cboPayMode.Text + "','" + txtChequeNo.Text + "','" + txtBankNameBranch.Text + "','"
                    + txtPUPrice.Text + "','" + txtPPrice.Text + "')";

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ObjCon.con.ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("StockProc", con))
            {
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date_of_Added", dtpNewProduct.Value));
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnvType", cboType.Text));
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TypeSize", txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text));
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Size", txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text));
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Desc", txtDesc.Text));
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", nudQty.Value));
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quality", nudQuality.Value));

                //http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Callstoredprocedureandpassintheparameter.htm
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnvType", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = cboType.Text;
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TypeSize", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = txtTypeSize1.Text + "X" + txtTypeSize2.Text;
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Size", SqlDbType.NVarChar )).Value=txtSize1.Text + "X" + txtSize2.Text;
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Desc", SqlDbType.Variant)).Value=txtDesc.Text;
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty",SqlDbType.Int)).Value= nudQty.Value;
                //cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quality", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = nudQuality.Value;

                con.Open();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Your Details has been Saved\rThank You", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Following Error Occurred" + ex, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```